# ChildView in FullScreenCover is recreated every time if ContentView is updated

Tags: swift, swiftui, fullscreen, swiftui-list

I have a question related to the next behavior.

I have `ContentView` with a list of views where the corresponding view models are passed. The user can click by some view. At the moment full-screen modal dialog will be shown according to the passed type. It's fine.
At some time my view models are being updated and the whole `ContentView` will be reloaded. The problem is: fullScreenCover is called and `ChildEventView` is recreated. How to prevent recreating `ChildEventView`?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var fullScreenType: FullScreenType?

    // some stuff

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(eventListViewModel.cardStates.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    let eventVM = eventListViewModel.eventVMs[index]
                    EventCardView(eventViewModel: eventVM, eventId: $selectedEvent.eventId) {
                        self.fullScreenType = .type1
                    }
                    // some other views
                }
            }
        }  
        .fullScreenCover(item: $fullScreenType, onDismiss: {
            self.fullScreenType = nil
        }, content: { fullScreenType in
            switch fullScreenType {
                case .type1:
                return ChildEventView(selectedEvent.eventId).eraseToAnyView()
                // some other cases
            } 
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be always recreated because it is a value constructed in closure call.

Comment: @Asperi Sorry, what value do you mean?

Comment: `ChildEventView` is a struct and structs are [value types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

Comment: @pawello2222, yep. I know it. So it seems there is no way...

Comment: Instead of preventing refreshing the view, try to make it *remember* its state, so on every refresh it *looks* the same.

Comment: @pawello2222, yeah, I will do `@StateObject` inside ChildEventView.